# Ubuntu App store doesn't show any installed application

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, uninstall, software-uninstall, ubuntu-store

I am unable to uninstall apps from my device as the Ubuntu Software center goes blank whenever I click the Installed application tab.

[image: The screen is stuck with a blank screen]

Comment: Try closing the program, then a `sudo apt -f install`, and assuming no errors again, try using Ubuntu/Gnome Software again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing and reinstalling `gnome-software`. As [Fix Ubuntu Software Center not loading issue in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.fosslinux.com/1768/fix-ubuntu-software-center-not-loading-issue-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts.htm) advises, you can do this by running:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

Comment: I am still unable to use Ubuntu software. This link helped to install the Gnome software center which is almost the same. Thanks